# CorDapp to demonstrate CompositeKey usage with Linearstate: Flow throws exception "Could not find Party for Anonymous(DLDHEGSYz...)"

Tags: corda

I am trying to make use of Composite Key feature to show how an asset on the ledger could be controlled using a composite key. I get following error in my flow code:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find Party for Anonymous(DLHpGSdYSvv7vLRGJuuZSsTWQpk7ehkB7B1K1bzV68YmY7)

at net.corda.core.identity.IdentityUtils.groupAbstractPartyByWellKnownParty(IdentityUtils.kt:47)
at net.corda.core.identity.IdentityUtils.groupAbstractPartyByWellKnownParty(IdentityUtils.kt:63)
at net.corda.core.flows.FinalityFlow.getPartiesToSend(FinalityFlow.kt:96)
at net.corda.core.flows.FinalityFlow.call(FinalityFlow.kt:54)
at net.corda.core.flows.FinalityFlow.call(FinalityFlow.kt:28)
at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:290)
at com.example.flow.ExampleFlow$Initiator.call(ExampleFlow.kt:102)
at com.example.flow.ExampleFlow$Initiator.call(ExampleFlow.kt:34)
```

**Below is my State definition**

```
data class LandState(val alice: Party, val bob: Party, override val linearId: UniqueIdentifier = UniqueIdentifier()): LinearState{

val owner: AbstractParty = AnonymousParty (CompositeKey.Builder().addKeys(alice.owningKey, bob.owningKey).build())
override val participants: List<AbstractParty> = listOf(owner)}
```

**Below is my contract code**

```
 override fun verify(tx: LedgerTransaction) {
    val command = tx.commands.requireSingleCommand<Commands.Create>()
    requireThat {

        "No inputs should be consumed when issuing an IOU." using (tx.inputs.isEmpty())
        "Only one output state should be created." using (tx.outputs.size == 1)
        val out = tx.outputsOfType<LandState>().single()
        "Command must be signed by the Composite key holder" using (command.signers.contains(out.owner.owningKey))


    }
}
```

**Below is my Flow**

```
object ExampleFlow {
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class Initiator( val alice: Party,
                val bob: Party) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
    /**
     * The progress tracker checkpoints each stage of the flow and outputs the specified messages when each
     * checkpoint is reached in the code. See the 'progressTracker.currentStep' expressions within the call() function.
     */
    companion object {
        object GENERATING_TRANSACTION : Step("Generating transaction based on new IOU.")
        object VERIFYING_TRANSACTION : Step("Verifying contract constraints.")
        object SIGNING_TRANSACTION : Step("Signing transaction with our private key.")
        object GATHERING_SIGS : Step("Gathering the counterparty's signature.") {
            override fun childProgressTracker() = CollectSignaturesFlow.tracker()
        }

        object FINALISING_TRANSACTION : Step("Obtaining notary signature and recording transaction.") {
            override fun childProgressTracker() = FinalityFlow.tracker()
        }

        fun tracker() = ProgressTracker(
                GENERATING_TRANSACTION,
                VERIFYING_TRANSACTION,
                SIGNING_TRANSACTION,
                GATHERING_SIGS,
                FINALISING_TRANSACTION
        )
    }

    override val progressTracker = tracker()

    /**
     * The flow logic is encapsulated within the call() method.
     */
    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
        // Obtain a reference to the notary we want to use.
        val notary = serviceHub.networkMapCache.notaryIdentities[0]

        // Stage 1.
        progressTracker.currentStep = GENERATING_TRANSACTION
        // Generate an unsigned transaction.
        val landState = LandState(alice, bob)
       // val iouState = IOUState(iouValue, serviceHub.myInfo.legalIdentities.first(), otherParty)

        val txCommand = Command(IOUContract.Commands.Create(), listOf(landState.owner.owningKey))
        val txBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary)
                .addOutputState(landState, IOU_CONTRACT_ID)
                .addCommand(txCommand)

        // Stage 2.
        progressTracker.currentStep = VERIFYING_TRANSACTION
        // Verify that the transaction is valid.

        // Stage 3.
        progressTracker.currentStep = SIGNING_TRANSACTION
        // Sign the transaction.
        val partSignedTx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder)

        // Stage 4.
        progressTracker.currentStep = GATHERING_SIGS
        // Send the state to the counterparty, and receive it back with their signature.
        val otherPartyFlow = initiateFlow(bob)
        val fullySignedTx = subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(partSignedTx, setOf(otherPartyFlow), GATHERING_SIGS.childProgressTracker()))

        txBuilder.verify(serviceHub)

        // Stage 5.
        progressTracker.currentStep = FINALISING_TRANSACTION
        // Notarise and record the transaction in both parties' vaults.
        return subFlow(FinalityFlow(fullySignedTx))
    }
}

@InitiatedBy(Initiator::class)
class Acceptor(val otherPartyFlow: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
        val signTransactionFlow = object : SignTransactionFlow(otherPartyFlow) {
            override fun checkTransaction(stx: SignedTransaction) = requireThat {

            }
        }

        return subFlow(signTransactionFlow)
    }
}}
```

Am I missing anything? The owner field in the above sate is of type AnonymousParty since composite key is of type public key and not a well known certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `CollectSignaturesFlow` with `CompositeKey`s. You need to define your own custom flow for collecting the required signatures.

Why? Because `CollectSignaturesFlow` works out who to request signatures from based on the parties listed in the commands. Since the `CompositeKey` does not correspond to a specific party, the node does not know who to request a signature from and throws an exception.